# How do you detect last row for MOVE in PostgreSQL

Tags: c, postgresql

My code:

```
PGresult *res = PQexec(m_IConnection, "MOVE NEXT in my_cursor_name");

ExecStatusType status =  PQresultStatus(res);

if (status != PGRES_COMMAND_OK)
{
    PQclear(res);
    return;
}
```

But it does not fail after it reaches the last row.
I've searched all over and can find no reference for detecting the end of rows.

Comment: Not too familiar with libpq, but it looks like `PQcmdTuples(res)` should return `"0"` once you hit the end

Comment: OK, I had tried PQntuples(res), but that did not work (always returned 0), but I will try PQcmdTuples(res). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the first comment,

> if(!stricmp(PQcmdTuples(res), "0"))

works to check for the last row of the MOVE